# Implicit constructor/inherited constructor and user-defined constructor different behaviour

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that automatically runs a function for a class when starting the application:

```
template<class T> struct RegClass;

template <typename T>
struct AutoRegister {
  AutoRegister() { (void)&ourRegisterer; }
private:
  static RegClass<T> ourRegisterer;
};

template <typename T>
RegClass<T> AutoRegister<T>::ourRegisterer;

template<class T>
struct RegClass {
  RegClass() {
    printf("registering\n");
  }
};
```

To use it for a class, I simply inherit from `AutoRegister<T>`:

```
struct Foo : AutoRegister<Foo>{
  Foo() {}
};
```

In this example, the application will print out "registering", even without ever instatiating an object of type `Foo`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc1678b1a18e8971

However, it seems like defining the constructor for `Foo` is required to observe this behaviour. The implicit constructor, or inheriting a base class's constructor is not enough: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54c53afe2724cdf

Thanks for linking [What are rules for a class static variable initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782361/what-are-rules-for-a-class-static-variable-initialization?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I took a look at inheriting constructors, and they have the same 'defined-when-odr-used' rule as implicit constructors, which explains that part too

Comment: Which application?